# Unexpected datasize issue with snappy compressed parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, snappy

```
df1 - large dataset
df2 = df1.sample(tiny_fraction)

df1 is written to disk as a parquet with snappy compression (~75GB)
df2 is written to disk as a parquet with snappy compression (~90GB)

df3 = read df2's saved parquet
# set sql context to use snappy compression
df3.partition(1).save() -> (~100MB)

df4 = read df1's saved parquet
df4.sample(tiny_fraction).partition(1).save() -> (~100MB)
```

The file size of the subsampled dataframe (without repartitioning) was larger than the original dataset
Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could happen?

Comment: sounds very strange indeed. How many files are written? and how big are they? is it the same number of files as the large dataset?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?